# Predefine Derived Class

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to predefine a derived class as follows,

```
class Base{

}

class Derived;

class Unreleated{
   Base* ptr;
public:
  Unreleated& operator, (const Unreleated& m){
    static_cast<Derived*>(ptr); // pointer is a derived.

    return *this;
  }


}

class Derived : public Base{
 //this is a container holding a bunch of unrelated.
}
```

but I am getting invalid static cast from Base* to Derived* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the definition of `Unreleated::operator,` to after the definition of `Derived`.

```
class Base{

};

class Derived;

class Unreleated{
   Base* ptr;
public:
  Unreleated& operator, (const Unreleated& m);

};

class Derived : public Base{
 //this is a container holding a bunch of unrelated.
};

  Unreleated& Unreleated::operator, (const Unreleated& m){
    static_cast<Derived*>(ptr); // pointer is a derived.

    return *this;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to `static_cast` from base->child or child->base the relationship has to be known to the compiler at the point the cast is made.

Since it really is unrelated, define your `Unrelated` class after both base and derived are defined to properly establish the inheritance relationship.

If `Derived` is actually holding a bunch of `Unrelated` by value, you have an unsolvable circular dependence. You'll have to rethink your design to enable it to work the way you want. Without more full details it's hard to help further.